# Numpy Python: How to get the most frequent 20 items from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop

I have an array of strings. I want to get the most frequent 20 items from the list.

Comment: Please could you provide sample input and output (as well as any code you've tried) ?

Comment: Is it a list of strings or an array? An [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be better.

Comment: Also take a look at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) docs, especially the `.most_common` method.